What is the best practice to extract claims on spring security
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
   return Jwts
             .parser()
             .verifyWith(getSignInKey())
             .build()
             .parseSignedClaims(token)
             .getPayload();
}

private Foo extractFoo(String token){
    Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claims.getFoo();
}

private Bar extractBar(String token){
    Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claims.getBar();
}

Is the code above or below good practice to extract data and why? Thanks for your contribute!
private Date extractFoo(String token){
    Claims claims = Jwts
                .parser()
                .verifyWith(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token)
                .getPayload();
    return claims.getFoo();
}

private Date extractBar(String token){
    Claims claims = Jwts
                .parser()
                .verifyWith(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseSignedClaims(token)
                .getPayload();
    return claims.getBar();
}

On top we will be bearing with jwts' chain once, but on bottom each time we extract something.

the two code blocks are pretty much identical, what exactly are you asking?

Thank you for feedback I edited the question.

to answer your question - both options are fine, in the first one there is less code duplication which is kind of a plus, but for such a simple code it doesn't really matter
